# connecting playframework with mysql(Data is not adding into the table)

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.2

I am new to the Play framework.I connected Play with mysql.But the data I am submitting through the form I have created is not adding in the database table.I am getting an exception

`[PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!]`

The code I used is

```
public static Result addBar(){
    Bar bar= Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    bar.save();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

Comment: HOW did you connect MySQL?

Comment: I created a lib/ directory in the root of my project and then added jar files to that directory.I am using Java only

Comment: I created a lib/ directory in the root of my project and then added jar files to that directory.I am using Java

Comment: Please post your bar.save() code

Answer (score 1):

In play you don't need to add a database driver manually. Just add the MySQL dependency to your "build.sbt" file like described in the links below from the documentation. For example: `libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"`.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaDatabase
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies

After you added the dependency you have to add the connection information in the "conf/application.conf" file. Therefore you need to uncomment the following lines and add your specific informations.

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://host/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=yourdb
db.default.password="supersecretpw"
```

If you want to use an ORM you can start with "ebean" by adding `libraryDependencies += javaEbean` to the dependencies and uncomment the following line in the "conf/application.conf" file:

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

This tells play that your model classes are stored in the package "models".

To use ebeans methods your classes have to be annotated with `@Entity` and need to extend `play.db.ebean.Model`.
The documentation at playframework.com on this topic is very detailed.

I hope that helped.